# The file is in use by IIS Express Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've an image in asp.net application and I resize and convert it for several times , but sometimes it's used by IIS Express process.
and I can't resize or convert it.
How to free IIS Express handle or how to bypass it?
is engaging IIS Express before publishing normal or I should exactly handle such situation?

this piece of code is for replacing two images:

```
public static void Replace(string OldPicture, Stream NewPicture)
{
   Bitmap OldImage = new Bitmap(OldPicture); 
   ImageFormat format = OldImage.RawFormat;
   Bitmap NewImage = new Bitmap(NewPicture);
   OldImage.Dispose();
   NewImage.Save(OldPicture, format);
   NewImage.Dispose();
   return;
}
```

Oldpicture is in use while saving via NewImage.save

Comment: [Needed is a minimal verifiable code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Question is updated.

Comment: Try to .Dispose (as soon as possible) even (NewImage.Width == OldImage.Width) && (NewImage.Height == OldImage.Height) is false.

Comment: @mlauth another update has been applied.

Comment: Free the stream if it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happen if the File is open. Possible you have to call `.Dispose()` or work with `using(...){...}`.

Dispose Example:

```
Bitmap source = new Bitmap(filePath);
Rectangle croptRect = new Rectangle((int)cropX, (int)cropY, (int)resizeWidth, (int)resizeHeight);
Bitmap target = source.Clone(croptRect, source.PixelFormat);
source.Dispose();
// working ...
target.Dispose();
```

Using Example:

```
if (!File.Exists(_path)) using (File.Open(_path)) { }
```